# Automate ssh-keygen -t rsa so it DOES ask for a passphrase

Tags: ssh, key-pair

I'm putting together a set of instructions for generating public/private key pairs for my server. Users will be non-technical. I'd like to give them a command that *requires* them to enter a passphrase, as opposed to simply *prompting* for it. (Do note, I understand that it's possible for people to follow their own path and circumvent these instructions; I'm not looking for something bulletproof, just something that guides them as strongly as possible along the preferred path.

Possible? I checked the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen), but if the answer's there I'm not understanding it.

Comment: I don't know the OS that your users will be using; however, you could ask them to use the SSH_ASKPASS environment variable to setup a graphical promt for the ssh password.

Comment: Thanks -- I was looking for something that would generically work on common command line interfaces, so I suppose that means BASH (default in Ubuntu, yes?) and whatever Mac OS X uses. (I have separate instructions for Windows/PuTTY.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a shell script to prompt for the passphrase, something like this:

```
passphrase=""
while [ -z "$passphrase" ]; do
    read -p "Passphrase: " passphrase
done
ssh-keygen -N $passphrase -t rsa
```

It will keep prompting until they enter a string in the passphrase.  You might want to make it smoother, but it'll get you started.

Comment: Thank you! For my purposes, I think this amounts to "no, not possible" or at least "not practical" -- because getting a non-technical user to create or install a script and then run it is pretty undesirable. Still, very helpful to know -- thanks!

Comment: I see, The -N "passphrase" option might be your best bet in your instructions, it will give the impression that it is required :)

Comment: Ah, now I understand what that's for...misunderstood the man page. Thanks, I do think that's the best solution!